# How to use Python re to remove all sub-strings starting with letters or numbers and ending with "PM"

Tags: python, text, nlp, python-re

I found some random codes caused by image files in my text file and I want to remove those random codes, which start with letters or numbers but end with "PM":
for example, there is a text:

```
iSD08LXjpg2021330401PM大陸不可以給60歲以上人士打香港專找60歲以上人士去打，做白老鼠

日本與美國比還是很不錯的USA死亡才多呢日媒體報道jpg2021321056PM
```

An ideal result would be:

```
大陸不可以給60歲以上人士打香港專找60歲以上人士去打，做白老鼠

日本與美國比還是很不錯的USA死亡才多呢日媒體報道
```

but I don't know how to use re to remove it.

Comment: If you remove all English characters from your text will it work for you?

Comment: The ideal result contains the text "USA" so the ideal solution won't just remove all English characters.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep English words that have actual meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove every continuous segment of roman letters plus arabic numerals that end with PM. This is achieved by a simple regular expression:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*PM`

`a-z` describes the range of all lowercase latin letters, equivalent for `A-Z` and `0-9`. `*` indicates any amount of characters since your string can likely have arbitrary length. `PM` is the fixed end string.

Of course, you have to make sure these strings don't contain special characters like `ü`. If they do, add groups of characters as appropriate.

The actual python code would then be

```py
    re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*PM',"",inputtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` to remove all ascii (ord 0-127) characters at the start or end of the string.

```
import re

s1 = 'iSD08LXjpg2021330401PM大陸不可以給60歲以上人士打香港專找60歲以上人士去打，做白老鼠'
s2 = '日本與美國比還是很不錯的USA死亡才多呢日媒體報道jpg2021321056PM'
```

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[\x00-\x7F]+|[\x00-\x7F]+$', '', s1)
'大陸不可以給60歲以上人士打香港專找60歲以上人士去打，做白老鼠'

>>> re.sub(r'^[\x00-\x7F]+|[\x00-\x7F]+$', '', s2)
'日本與美國比還是很不錯的USA死亡才多呢日媒體報道'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but those random codes actually don’t just appear at the start and the end, sometimes they are in the middle of a text